# How can I map over a vector and get a vector?

Tags: elisp, mapping

The only thing I've found that works is

```
(eval `(vector ,@(mapcar #'1+ [1 2 3 4])))
=> [2 3 4 5]
```

but that seems *far* too complicated to be the 'right' way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`cl-map`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Mapping-over-Sequences.html), instead:

```
(cl-map 'vector #'1+ [1 2 3 4])
```

A little extra background: `cl-map` is the [Common Lisp `map` function](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm) that generalizes to sequence types:

```
(cl-map 'vector #'1+ '[1 2 3 4]) ;; ==> [2 3 4 5]
(cl-map 'list   #'1+ '(1 2 3 4)) ;; ==> (2 3 4 5)
(cl-map 'string #'upcase "abc")  ;; ==> "ABC"
```

It can also convert between sequence types (eg, here, the input is a list and the output is a vector):

```
(cl-map 'vector #'1+ '(1 2 3 4)) ;; ==> [2 3 4 5]
```

Comment: 18 seconds the 'winner' :) Don't the `cl` libraries give compiler warnings, though?  (Mostly because the FSF is obnoxious?)

Comment: FWIW, I think the byte compilation problems were related to the old `cl` library rather than the rejiggered `cl-lib` library.  I don't for example, get any warnings when I `(defun fnx () (cl-map 'vector #'1+ '[1 2 3 4]))` and then `(byte-compile 'fnx)`.

Comment: Even if you use the compatibility cl-lib, I think you'll get warnings on older emacs (24.2). I wouldn't worry about it though, you have to pick your battles.

Comment: Note that this dynamically creates a list, then converts that to a vector and discards the temporary list.

Answer (score 15):

Since I was beat by 18 seconds, here's a simpler and safer way to do it without the cl library. It also doesn't evaluate the elements.

```
(apply #'vector (mapcar #'1+ [1 2 3 4])) ;; => [2 3 4 5]
```

Comment: That's also quite nice!  Re: your earlier comment about older Emacs: it seems especially helpful if you have to anticipate legacy users.  It seems most helpful if you only have to use it in a couple of spots, at which point you can trade off the slight inconvenience against avoiding the `cl-lib` dependency.

Comment: Very nifty!! I didn't think about using `apply`.

Comment: I think `(apply #'vector ...)` might be ever so slightly faster, but for completeness, it can also be replaced with `(vconcat ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

The not so elegant inplace-variant for the case that the original vector is no longer needed afterwards and memory allocation is time-critical (e.g. the vector is big).

```el
(setq x [1 2 3 4])

(cl-loop for var across-ref x do
         (setf var (1+ var)))
```

The result is stored in `x`. If you need the form to return `x` in the end you can add `finally return x` as follows:

```el
(cl-loop for var across-ref x do
         (setf var (1+ var))
         finally return x)
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, using `seq`:

```
(require 'seq)
(seq-into (seq-map #'1+ [1 2 3 4]) 'vector)
```

Comment: There is a deleted answer from [Fólkvangr](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/19761/f%c3%b3lkvangr) 2018-11-12 with the exact same `seq-into` line. The user has deleted his answer for the following reason: "
My solution is less relevant because the seq library uses the underlying Common Lisp extensions. – Fólkvangr May 16 at 8:53"

Comment: @Tobias I guess I'd disagree with that logic. Everything is going to end up using vconcat or vector anyway, but the different interface paradigms are useful to have on record.

Comment: No problem. I just saw the deleted answer of Fólkvangr (almost) matching yours and wanted to notify you. For whatever reason seeing deleted answers requires 10000 rep:-(.

Comment: @Tobias yeah, I never really understood why those privileges were site-specific :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop

```
(let ((v (vector 1 2 3 4)))
  (dotimes (i (length v))
    (aset v i (1+ (aref v i))))
  v)
;; => [2 3 4 5]
```

Sometimes you don't want to modify the original vector, you can make a copy

```
(let* ((v0 (vector 1 2 3 4))
       (v (copy-sequence v0)))
  (dotimes (i (length v))
    (aset v i (1+ (aref v i))))
  (list v0 v))
;; => ([1 2 3 4] [2 3 4 5])
```

or create a new vector from scratch

```
(let* ((v0 (vector 1 2 3 4))
       (v (make-vector (length v0) nil)))
  (dotimes (i (length v))
    (aset v i (1+ (aref v0 i))))
  (list v0 v))
;; => ([1 2 3 4] [2 3 4 5])
```