# How to map a function over several values?

Tags: elisp, functions

I have a function `foo-function` that takes the variable `x` and performs a specific action.  The variable `x` comes before the definition of `foo-function`:

```
(defvar x "value1")

(defun foo-function ()
  (blabalabla x))
```

I would like to define a new function `foo-function2` which takes several variables `value1, value2, value3, ....` of `x` (the number of variables is indeterminate) and runs the function `foo-function` for these variables, i.e., the following action:

```
(foo-function2 "value1" "value2" "value3", ...)
```

It should result in the execution of `foo-function` for the values `value1, value2, value3, ....` of `x`.

How do I define this function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you want [`mapcar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html).  From the docstring:

> `(mapcar FUNCTION SEQUENCE)`
>
> Apply FUNCTION to each element of SEQUENCE, and make a list of the results.
>   The result is a list just as long as SEQUENCE.
>   SEQUENCE may be a list, a vector, a bool-vector, or a string.

```
(defun identity-fnx (x)
  x)

(mapcar #'identity-fnx '(1 2 3)) ; => (1 2 3)

(defvar x '(a b c d))
(mapcar #'identity-fnx x)        ; => (a b c d)
```

Comment: n.b. Use `mapc` instead to avoid accumulating the return value sequence, if you don't want that.

Comment: @phils: right on; I wasn't sure if he wanted to accumulate or not.  And another n.b. on your n.b. is to use a more general option like `cl-map` (compare [How can I map over a vector and get a vector?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2961/how-can-i-map-over-a-vector-and-get-a-vector)).

Comment: Little nitpick: `identity` is built-in :)